# household_objects_database with gazebo (or blender)

Tags: ros, gazebo, household-objects-database, blender

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I'm trying to use the objects from the household_objects_database in gazebo.
At the moment I am trying to export the data from the objects_database_node/get_model_mesh-call to a format, which can be imported into blender to export it as .dae-file.

My way at the moment is:

- first to call objects_database_node/get_model_mesh and save it to a file
- afterwards to read in the data and trying to write an .obj-file.

The second point is the problem. I don't know how to interpret the data. They have the form:

```
return_code: 
  code: -1
mesh: 
  type: 0
  dimensions: []
  triangles: [74, 390, ... , 452]
  vertices: 
    - 
      x: 0.00321499991417
      y: -0.0341199989319
      z: 0.101269996643
    - 
      x:...
```

So clearly the second part is a list of 3D-Points. And the first part must be some sort of indices to build triangles. But the problem is, without the knowledge if it is a list of triangles, a triangle-strip, or so on it is not very useful. I tried most of the possibilities I can think of and they don't give sufficient results.

So I need some help for interpreting the data, or by figuring out a way to get this models into gazebo.

Thanks a lot for helping

Philipp

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10196/household_objects_database-with-gazebo-(or-blender)/) by [Philipp](https://answers.ros.org/users/661/philipp/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2011-06-07

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2011-06-08**:
For guessing, you could check if triangles length is divisible by 3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi Philipp,

Type 0, means you are manipulating a sphere. The triangle array are triangles indices and the 3D points are the vertices of the mesh.

You should take a look at the mesh part [here](http://www.ros.org/wiki/household%20objects).
And maybe the [message description](http://www.ros.org/doc/api/household_objects_database_msgs/html/srv/GetModelMesh.html) will help you too.

Guido

---

Originally posted by [Guido](https://answers.ros.org/users/279/guido/) with karma: 514 on 2011-06-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Matei Ciocarlie](https://answers.ros.org/users/36/matei-ciocarlie/) on 2011-06-08**:
I think the bug causing all meshes to have type 0 might still be around in the released version... Please ignore the type field for now. Other than that, Guido is correct, it is a list of triangle indices (a triangle soup if you wish)

**Comment by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) on 2011-06-08**:
Just a quick note: there has been a bug which caused the type to always be 0. I think this has been fixed already, but I'm not sure if the database services running at Willow are using the fixed version.